# Delete text from 1 file and add to the other in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm making a movie organizer for myself to manage the movies I downloaded on my computer. I'm using batch to do the job. I already finished the project successfully, however I need to add a few features from time to time to keep my program fresh and easy to use.

The feature I'm adding today is a "mark movie as watched" feature. The method I want to use seems quite simple, and it must be. The idea behind this method is the following:

I have a `.txt` file that contains a list of movies I have on the computer. New movies can be added to the list through the batch program. I made a simple code in the past that puts a string `"MovieNumber1"` before every line of each movie. The `Movies.txt` file looks as follows:

````
MovieNumber1 Name: Example Movie 1

MovieNumber1 Year: 2000

MovieNumber1 Desc: This is a description

MovieNumber1 Path: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Videos\movie1.mp4

MovieNumber1 ----------------------------------------------------------------

MovieNumber2 Name: Example Movie 2

MovieNumber2 Year: 2002

MovieNumber2 Desc: This is a description

MovieNumber2 Path: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Videos\movie2.mp4

MovieNumber2 ---------------------------------------------------------------- ```
````

I know, it's not very neat. But it does the job.

What I need now, to make the new "mark as watched" feature, is to delete the lines of a certain movie, and write them in another **txt** file called `WatchedMovies.txt`

I tried this code, which I wanted to search for `"MovieNumber%moviechoice%"`, delete all the lines with that string from `Movies.txt`, and paste them in `WatchedMovies.txt`.

```
FindStr /B /V /C:"MovieNumber%moviechoice%" Movies.txt < WatchedMovies.txt
```

**Note:** `%moviechoice%` is a variable the program asks the user for before he reaches this stage. This variable is just a number.

For example, if the user chose the second movie, he will type `"2"` to select it. Then he could either watch the movie or mark it as watched. If he decides to watch it, my code will start the movie successfully. If he decides to mark it as watched, the program should search for `"MovieNumber2"` in `Movies.txt` (since the user entered 2 previously), delete all the lines containing `"MovieNumber2"` in `Movies.txt` and paste them in `WatchedMovies.txt`. If this worked successfully, the user should be able to see the un-watched movies in `Movies.txt` and the watched movies in `WatchedMovies.txt`.

What this code is doing now is copying everything without `"MovieNumber2"` (IE. copying all line with other MovieNumbers) and pasting them in `WatchedMovies.txt`

How can I change it to do what I want?

Comment: Have you not considered using a file format other than `.txt`? _(csv, json, xml)_, One that can be parsed by a scripting engine designed for parsing such things. Batch files are absolutely the wrong choice for your task.

Comment: @Compo I'm using batch for it's simplicity. I barely know any languages, and batch does the job. It has a few cons here and there, but it works for what I need.

Comment: What I'm telling you Daniel, is you're wrong, 'batch' is not simpler!

Comment: While this can be done in a batch file script, it could also be done in assembly language. But, almost no one would.  This would be far easier to manage as a JSON or CSV file. Heed Compo's suggestion.

Comment: @lit I believe you're right. I've looked around for a program that does exactly this job but I found nothing. That's what led me to try and create my own. Unfortunately, I don't know how to code in any language, I only know know to use batch. However, I am willing to learn a new language and implement it to make a project such as this, since I have a lot of time on my hands. In the end, I am making this project so I make my life easier. What language do you recommend for doing such a task, and do you think I can build it if I'd still be new to the language?

Comment: If you want to learn a programming language, I would suggest PowerShell or Python. If you just want to get the job done, I would suggest going with a spreadsheet like LibreOffice Calc. https://www.libreoffice.org/